# How to write formulas with variable starting column in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that runs 4 formulas.

```
Sub Kit()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i, n, x As Integer
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report KIT (2)")
ws.Select
LastRow = Sheets("Report KIT (2)").Range("A" & Sheets("Report KIT (2)").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow
On Error Resume Next
If Range("BR" & i) >= Range("AM" & i) Then
Range("BS" & i) = "C"
Else: Range("BS" & i) = "GA + C"
End If
Next i

For i = 3 To LastRow
On Error Resume Next
 Range("BT" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-1]=""C"",(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C[-6],RC[-6]))*(VLOOKUP('Report KIT (2)'!RC[-6],GA_C!C[-71]:C[-68],4,0)),SUM((RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C[-6],RC[-6]))*(VLOOKUP('Report KIT (2)'!RC[-6],GA_C!C[-71]:C[-68],4,0)),(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C[-6],RC[-6],C[-1],""GA + C""))*(VLOOKUP('Report KIT (2)'!RC[-6],GA_C!C[-71]:C[-69],3,0))))"
    Next i

For i = 3 To LastRow
On Error Resume Next
Range("BU" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]+RC[-1]"
Next i

For i = 3 To LastRow
On Error Resume Next
Range("BV" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-2]+RC[-5])*0.13"
Next i


End Sub
```

I would like to modify it in order to repeat the same calculation, but after each full circle of all 4 formulas to move starting columns: BS; BT; BU; BV in 4 cells forward (so on the next circle they become BW; BX; BY; BZ, then on the 3rd run CA; CB; CC; CD etc.) And i would like to loop it for 11 times. Can anyone help with it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below. I have referenced the columns with numbers, using the cells property. After each formula loop the column increments by 1.

Also remember that if you declare variables like this `Dim i, n, x As Integer` it will only declare `x` as an integer, `i` and `n` will be declared as variants.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Kit()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, x As Integer, j As Integer, mcol As Integer
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report KIT (2)")
    ws.Select
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    mcol = 71
    For j = 1 To 11
        For i = 3 To LastRow
            On Error Resume Next
            If Cells(i, mcol - 1) >= Range("AM" & i) Then
                Cells(i, mcol) = "C"
            Else
                Cells(i, mcol) = "GA + C"
            End If
        Next i
        mcol = mcol + 1

        For i = 3 To LastRow
            On Error Resume Next
            Cells(i, mcol) = "D" ''formula using mcol
        Next i
        mcol = mcol + 1

        For i = 3 To LastRow
            On Error Resume Next
            Cells(i, mcol) = "E" ''formula using mcol
        Next i
        mcol = mcol + 1

        For i = 3 To LastRow
            On Error Resume Next
            Cells(i, mcol) = "F" ''formula using mcol
        Next i
        mcol = mcol + 1
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can i ask, if i'm using a mcol for the formula: "=RC[-4]+RC[-1]", where starting cell is mcol, how to rewrite this formula using mcol?

Comment: are the cells you're referencing in the formula static, or do they need to be dynamic in the same way?

Comment: i always start with the mcol that is dynamic and increases by 1 after each for (like in your code), then i use cells in a formula moving from mcol. For example, if mcol = 72, then "=RC[-4]+RC[-1]" must be something like column  68 + column 71

Comment: If every time you wish the formula to perform the calculation: mcol cell - 4 columns + mcol cell - 1 column, then you would just use the same formula every time. The formula is dynamic, so always adds the numbers in the cell 4 columns back and the cell in 1 column back.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 **new loops** and change the **range method** to **cells method**

```
For mainLoop = 1 To 11
    For newLoop = 0 To 4
        'demonstration of the change
        'in EDIT added the (newLoop * 4) * mainLoop  into the column increment
        For i = 3 To LastRow
            If Cells(i, 70 + (newLoop * 4) * mainLoop ) >= Cells(i, 39) Then 'change the right part of compare >= as needed
            Cells(i, 71 + (newLoop * 4) * mainLoop ) = "C"
            Else: Cells(i, 71 + (newLoop * 4)*mainLoop ) = "GA + C"
            End If
        Next i

        'repeat similar change in all other loops
        For i = 3 To LastRow
        '...
        Next i

        For i = 3 To LastRow
        '...
        Next i

        For i = 3 To LastRow
        '...
        Next i
    Next newLoop
Next mainLoop
```

### Edit 2

After correct comments from the author of the question...This should do the trick.

```
    For mainLoop = 0 To 10
    For newLoop = 0 To 3 'changed to 3
        For i = 3 To LastRow
            If Cells(i, 70 + newLoop * 4 + 16 * mainLoop) >= Cells(i, 39) Then 'change the right part of compare >= as needed
            Cells(i, 71 + newLoop * 4 + 16 * mainLoop) = "C"
            Else: Cells(i, 71 + newLoop * 4 + 16 * mainLoop) = "GA + C"
            End If
        Next i

        'repeat similar change in all other loops
        For i = 3 To LastRow
        '...
        Next i
        '...

    Next newLoop
Next mainLoop
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried it but seems it's not really what i need, because the starting column must always be moved forward for 4 cells. For example, 70, then 70 + 4 =74, then 74+4 = 78, then 78+4 = 82 etc. for 11 times, each time increasing starting column number +4.

Comment: Well that's what it should do. At first the `newLoop` is = 0 so the `70 + newLoop * 4` = 70, next loop the `newLoop` is = 1, so the `70 + newLoop * 4` = 74 etc.

Comment: you are right, but when it reaches newLoop = 4, it passes to mainLoop, so that during the 2nd circle from 11 it starts from newLoop = 0 again and passes back to 70 + 0 * 4= 70 etc., is not it?

Comment: Yes, true, we need to add the mainLoop to the increment. I'll edit the answer code. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thank You! but still seems that it is not completely right. Correct me, if i am wrong, after you reach 70 + 4*4* 1= 86, you pass to the next circle when mainLoop = 2 and newLoop = 0, so you get 70 + 0*4* 2 = 70 instead of 90 and then 70 + 1*4* 2 = 78 instead of 94. It makes me think that is easier to fix an additional cells and to make a starting cell number (70, 71 etc.) as variable. thanks again!

Comment: Oh, I'm failing at math horribly on this one :D. Added code in **Edit 2**.

Comment: Now seems working well :D I must admit it's quite a tricky way to get +4 cells each time using two variables (mainLoop and newLoop). Thank You!

Comment: Yes, some procedures are quite tricky. Please consider accepting the answer if it worked. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)